# Popover View Does Not Show Subviews

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, popover, subview

I have an iOS app that was created using storyboards with auto-layout.  The View Controllers are in a navigation controller.  Several steps down the navigation controller chain I have a button in VC1 that is connected to VC2 via a popover segue.  When I tap the button, a popover view appears but is blank.  I changed the background color of VC2 to see if the view was actually appearing.  It was.  No subviews were visible.  I have created and recreated VC2.  I have changed the sizes of the view, the subviews and the view controller.  I have manually and automatically created restraints.  I also created a test view controller outside of the navigation view controller.  It behaved the same as the view controllers in the navigation controller.

Just to check if I was completely incompetent, I created a new project with a storyboard that had one VC.  I placed a button in this VC with a popover segue to a second VC.  It worked as desired.  When the button was pressed a popover would appear and all subviews of the second VC would be visible.  I tried placing the first VC in a navigation controller with no change.  It continued to show the popover as it should.  I have compared the two projects and I can't find what the problem is.

My question is this: Does anyone out there know of some hidden setting that would cause this behavior? or Any suggestions on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a whole lot of time (and even rewriting my project from scratch) I finally found the solution.  Apparently, using size classes messes with popovers.  To solve this solution, I turned size classes off completely.  My app is iPad only so that worked for me.  According to this thread: [iOS8 Size-Classes and Popover Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559327/ios8-size-classes-and-popover-views) you can also use the Any/Any size class.  I was using Regular/Regular size class.  I hope this helps someone.